# if money is involved, is a multiplayer game gambling?

Tags: money, game, gambling, halal-haram

I am a owner of a game development company. Currently our team is working on a multiplayer shooter game. In that game, the user will purchase coins and play with others with some portion of that coin. Winners will get all the coin and after a certain amount of coins the winner can redeem that coin for real money. My question is:

1. Is this a gambling in eye of Islam? As it depends on player skill rather than luck then how could it be gambling?
2. If it is gambling then if I give them the opportunity to earn that coin from the game by doing some task then will the game still be gambling? (e.g. watching video ads will give the user 1 coin or something like that).

I am a pure Muslim and at least I don't want to do any forbidden things that is directly mentioned in the Holy Qur'an. If the project is related to gambling then how can I make it legal in an Islamic way? I mean what feature will make it not forbidden in the eyes of Islam, keeping in mind that I don't want to remove the coin playing system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As per your description of the system, what you're referring to comes under competitions with prize-money. **This is haraam** except for few cases:

> *Al-Tirmidhi (1700), al-Nasaa’i (3585), Abu Dawood (2574) and Ibn
> Majaah (2878) narrated that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah
> be upon him) said:* “There should be **no (money) prizes for competitions**
> except in archery, camel-racing and horse-racing.”

Here's a fatwa by *[islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/114530/football-soccer-competitions)* regarding competitions with prizes. But *[IslamWeb](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/339982/competing-in-video-games-to-win-prize)* also says that Maalikis have an opinion that if the nature of the competition is halaal, even if they don't fall in the above mentioned sports in the hadith, then the prizes are halaal in that case, although majority are still of the opinion that it is impermissible.

2. If the system of purchasing coins through real money is kept in place, then adding another method of earning money doesn't change the ruling. This is because it is just mixing halaal and haraam and the end product is haraam or at the very least mushbooh.

**As long as real money is involved in this scenario which comes from the competitors themselves, it cannot be halaal** *(Look at second part of this [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/114530/football-soccer-competitions) and also this [fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/339982/competing-in-video-games-to-win-prize))*. There is no need to further discuss about what ways it can be made halaal as this is off topic as per the site's policy.

**And Allah(SWT) knows best**

Comment: Then I have to stop my very valuable Project.... Thank Allah he clears my confusion by you...

Comment: crimson and @MDRahatIslamKhan please help me here [What exactly is considered gambling in the case of professional sports/gaming or any sports/gaming involving luck/chance?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67167/what-exactly-is-considered-gambling-in-the-case-of-professional-sports-gaming-or)